# Thymeleaf: interpolate variables without tag

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Using thymeleaf in spring boot project. Got a template with long texts and was wondering if it is possible to interpolate variables without using a tag. For example, instead of:

```
<div th:if="${someCondition}" th:remove="tag">
Foo bar long text <span th:text="${someVariable}" th:remove="tag"/>,lorem ipsum <span th:text="${anotherVariable}" th:remove="tag"/>
<span th:text="${thirdVariable}" th:remove="tag" />.
</div>
```

Something similar to this (e.g.: handlebars):

```
<div th:if="${someCondition}" th:remove="tag">
Foo bar long text {{someVariable}}, lorem ipsum {{anotherVariable}} {{thirdVariable}}.
</div>
```

The latter I found a lot easier to read and work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [expression inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining).

```
<div th:if="${someCondition}" th:remove="tag">
  Foo bar long text [[${someVariable}]], lorem ipsum [[${anotherVariable}]] [[${thirdVariable}]].
</div>
```